# How can I iterate through the python list, and stop to load the next URL before continuing the process?

Tags: python, list, selenium, loops, web-scraping

I have learned to accomplish *(using python)* building some different web scrapers with the purpose of scraping image URLs from one of our part manufacturer's websites for the sake of mass uploading a load sheet of products, with one of the columns consisting of the image URLs.

Since the URLs aren't simple (I can't simply iterate through a list of product numbers and append it to each new URL nor any of the simpler methods; I'm here because I have to be here) and since the site doesn't have a "search by product number" function, I went to the lists on their site. They had some really handy tools! You can add products by product number, and when you're done you can export that list as a `.csv` with the option to include the links to all of the corresponding product pages. Which was great, until I built my script and found out the hard way that they have a 250 item limit per list. For perspective, I have a little under 5,000 products to scrape (meaning I will need about 20 lists, with 19 full and the last one nearly full).

I mention all of this as the context for it is relevant to the code and issue at hand.

My goal now that I have really no other options is to take my code and modify it a bit to achieve the scraping through 20 separate lists. Right now, at the stage that is relevant, it gets a URL that goes to the link of their website for a list I have named `testlist` and it then refreshes the page just to make sure all of the elements are in order.

We were on the right page when I needed one list, but there's issue one: We can't just use one link anymore, as we will have to set something up to iterate through 250 items and create a new list about 20 times (or I can manually create the lists and have specific URLs to point to).

Our second issue at hand is the item limit itself. My for loop is one large one designed to iterate through the entire list of about 4,800 product numbers that I have, adding them one by one into the list on the same page. We need to break this up into chunks of 250 items per page, at most, and have it load up another list URL. I *could* go create those lists manually so that I would have specific URLs to point to, but, if it will be easier to add a function that just clicks and names it, that would be awesome. I can figure that part out myself, probably.

I don't know where to go from here. I have code that is built to handle one website list, on one URL, iterating through the product numbers in my python list, and then export that at the end.

I need my script to iterate through the same python list, stopping after 250 product numbers to load the next URL before continuing the process.

The part of my code that gets our list URL and then onwards into the scraper portion is as follows.

```
# get the url for our list
listurl = 'https://www.thewebsiteimscraping.com/products/list-manager?listid=3925' # <- this is the URL for one particular list; other lists will have different list IDs
alert_accept()
driver.get(listurl)
alert_accept()

############################################################################################

driver.refresh()
# import our list, the Select function, the By function for selections, expected conditions, and our time function so we can sleep 
from kiberlist import mfrnumbers
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time
# from testnumber import testnumbers as tlnum 


for number in mfrnumbers:
    
        # we find the listactions menu, and utilize the "add item" option
        WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#listActions")))
        alert_accept()
        print('Finding listactions...')
        select_am = Select(driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#listActions'))
        alert_accept()
        print("Found it. Selecting...")
        select_am.select_by_value('addItems')
        print('Selected. Next...')
        
        # paste our item number into the box paste it 
        print('Locating model number search....')
        inputidbox = driver.find_element_by_id('model-number-search')
        print('Located? Pasting model number...')
        inputidbox.send_keys(number)  
        
        # finally add our item
        additembutton = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.gtmAddItemToList')
        print('Located add item button...')
        additembutton.click()   
        print('Item number added. Next...')
        print('Locating blank space...')
        WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#addItemsToListModal > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > button:nth-child(1) > svg:nth-child(1) > path:nth-child(1)")))
        time.sleep(1)
        xbutton = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#addItemsToListModal > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > button:nth-child(1) > svg:nth-child(1) > path:nth-child(1)')
        xbutton.click()
        time.sleep(1)

 
        
# now we find the "export excel" option to get our csv for that list  
listactions = Select(driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#listActions'))
listactions.select_by_value('exportExcel')

# clicky clicky. user dialog will show up on screen asking if you want to save the file. user must manually click on save 
exportbutton = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#btnExportToExcel')
exportbutton.click()
```

My question is, how can I rearrange and/or modify this code to accomplish what I need? Is this the most efficient method of accomplishing this? What would you do, how would you handle this, and what code can I implement in order to achieve my goal if there are no better options?

It would be pretty useless to share the actual website links as you need an account with them in order to access lists and such.

Comment: You put a lot of effort into this question but the title ruins it! i would suggest updating this so your question can get more attention.

Comment: Hi! I edited out the fluff so that users can help you with your problem without distractions.

Comment: @Ironkey thank you! I am aware this wasn't a very clear question but I was not actually sure what to put there..

Comment: No problem! Hopefully, you get the help you need :)

Comment: @haise0 My pleasure!

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you have code that works for a single list, and now you just want it to work over smaller portions of that list.

Usually you see "convert list of lists into one flat list". This is the opposite.

I'm assuming mfrnumbers is your flat list. We'll create a [generator](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/functional.html#generators) function that given one flattened_list, it returns the `list_id` and the elements in that list. As stated in your question, you'll figure out how to actually get that list. So for now, I'm assuming the `list_id` is a simple integer.

This function `get_list(mfrnumbers)` will return those numbers in groups of `max_items_per_list`.  Technically, it returns an iterator that you will iterate over.

```
def get_list(flattened_list, max_items_per_list=250):
    # maybe you have some pattern for list names?
    list_id = 1

    while len(flattened_list) > 0:
        current_list = flattened_list[:max_items_per_list]
        yield list_id, current_list

        flattened_list = flattened_list[len(current_list):]
        list_id += 1
```

And we can call this function as follows:

```
for (myid, mylist) in get_list([1,2,3,4,5], max_items_per_list=2):
    print (myid, mylist)
```

Output:

```
1 [1, 2]
2 [3, 4]
3 [5]
```

So in your case, you would run your entire big loop `for number in mfrnumbers` as an inner loop but with the output of `get_list`.

```
for (myid, mylist) in get_list(mfrnumbers):
    # stop and do any loading for this new list...
    for number in mylist:
       .....
```